# Do the Claptrap collectable item counters reset if I die?

Tags: achievements, borderlands

When trying to get the "The Lubricator" achievement, a common trick is to hide out in a corner of a shed, let the Kamikaze Claptraps blow themselves up, go watch a movie and collect the items afterwards. If you're distracted or not careful enough, you might die (because MINAC runs you over, for instance). If I don't want to wait out 10 hours before each collection run, I need more short runs. If I die during one of those, does the counter reset, and I need to collect 25 within one "lifetime" or does that not matter.

- [This forum poster states it ***does*** reset with every death](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/borderlands/trophy/20897-The-Lubricator.html#17)
- [This other poster states it *does **not***](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/borderlands/trophy/20897-The-Lubricator.html#19)

Which is it?

PS: Same goes of course for the counters of *Pizzas, Slips, Bobbleheads, 3D-glasses, Fishes*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not reset between each death. The only condition is that you collect so many of each type, and that's it.